# SSDT - Data migrations between database versions

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a preferred way to handle data migrations between versions of databases using SSDT?

We have a large database project developed in SSDT, using post deployment scripts to insert/merge data to the database.

Now we're facing issues handling updates. We can't use merge scripts to update data because in some cases we need to manipulate the already existing data and therefore must implement custom update scripts.

I've looked into a solution using dacpac version number and verify which update scripts to run, but I realize that this solution has drawbacks.

What I have so far (pseudo code):

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[#GetDatabaseVersion](
@DbVersion NVARCHAR(64) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    select @DbVersion = type_version from msdb.dbo.sysdac_instances_internal where     instance_name = '$(DatabaseName)'
    RETURN
END


DECLARE @DbVersion NVARCHAR(64)
EXEC #GetDatabaseVersion @DbVersion = @DbVersion OUTPUT

IF @DbVersion = '2.4.0.0'
BEGIN
  --Do some data manipulation
END

IF @DbVersion = '2.5.0.0'
BEGIN
  --Do some more data manipulation
END
```

The drawbacks with the above solution is that I can't use GO statements in the IF-statements, and some of our code might be needing running the scripts in statement blocks.

Also is there any way to get the "DacVersion" from the SSDT project as an command variable?

Comment: I've seen some people store this in a table and then reference it from there. That's probably easier than trying to set and read the DACPAC version. Another possibility is to make sure that all of your scripts can be re-run (check for existence before insert, etc.).

Comment: It might be really hard to check for data existence, e.g. in case the user can change the data.